# Why was D'Angelo Russell underpaid during this free agency?

Tags: basketball, nba, finances

Why was D'Angelo Russell underpaid during this free agency?

Kevin Durant signed with the Nets for 164 million. Kyrie Irving signed with the Nets for 140 million. Russell is only sign-and-trading away from the Nets to the Warriors for 117 million.

Stephen A. Smith says it was because D'Lo was [busted for smoking weed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqee19QQxao). Is this true? Or are there other factors as to why D'Lo didn't get his money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'Angelo Russell received maximum money allowed to him, [according to Adrian Wojnarowski](https://twitter.com/wojespn/status/1145535080305242112). Therefore, he was not underpaid nor did he lose money as a result of possessing marijuana.

> Golden State and Brooklyn have agreed on a sign-and-trade, sending
>   D’Angelo Russell to the Warriors on a four-year, $117M maximum
>   contract, league sources tell ESPN.

What he is allowed to earn at a maximum is different from other players. First, he is a restricted free agent (as opposed to being an unrestricted free agent like Kevin Durant or Kyrie irving). Next, he has four years experience while Durant has 12 years and Irving has 8 years. Moreover, especially in the case of Durant, what [Durant] is allowed to earn at a maximum is higher since he makes All-NBA teams perennially. All these conditions and more, including the requirements to earn a "super max" deal, are addressed in the [NBA's Collective Bargaining Agreement](https://atlhawksfanatic.github.io/NBA-CBA/).